# How to programmatically request and release a feature license in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am wondering if there are commands to programmatically obtain and release shared licenses (libraries, binary export license etc.) for Dymola 2020x without having to shut down the entire program.

I am specifically interested in being able to obtain and release the code export License. I have tried these two options, but haven't had much success reliably releasing a license or obtaining a recently freed license (by another user) without having to close Dymola.

```
DymolaCommands.Others.RequestOption()
Advanced.EnableCodeExport
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding obtaining a license; I have been able pull a shared license with the following code:

- RequestOption("BinaryModelExport")

This only works if the license is not checked out by another user. Note it takes about 5 minutes to obtain the license when it has been "freed" by another user.

However I have had no success in pragmatically releasing the license after. I would love to be able to do this.